# How to stop animating GIF in SDWebImage?

Tags: swift, sdwebimage

I'm using SDWebImage to fetch images from web and display them.
But some are GIFs, how to stop the GIF?

Comment: Do you mean stop the animation? Or removing the gif?  I'd like to know the answer to both personally.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using >= v4.0; from the docs:

> Starting with the 4.0 version, we rely on FLAnimatedImage to take care of our animated images.

From `FLAnimatedImage`'s docs; there are 2 ways to control playback:

> // An FLAnimatedImageView can take an FLAnimatedImage and plays it automatically when in view hierarchy and `stops when removed`.
>
> // The animation can also be controlled with the UIImageView methods -`start`/`stop`/`isAnimating`.

Comment: I tried stopAnimating, but it didn't work. I will try it later.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to stop the animation is to simply set your SDAnimatedImageView to for example

```
sdAnimatedImageView.image = SDAnimatedImage(named: "your.gif")?.animatedImageFrame(at: 0)
```

that way you will get one frame of your gif only and it will not be animated :)

its a hack but does the job